# Using MatrixForm in a Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, output-formatting, gui-construction

I have declared some lists

```
vAwG = {{{0}, {0}}, {{1}, {1}}};
psi = {0, 1, 2, 3};
vBwB = {{{1}, {0}}, {{0}, {1}}};
```

and created a function

```
vBwGFunc[vAwGIn_, psiIn_, vBwBIn_] := RotationMatrix[psiIn] . vBwBIn + vAwGIn
```

and evaluated the following

```
Manipulate[vBwGFunc[vAwGIn, psiIn, vBwBIn],
  {vAwGIn, vAwG, ControlType -> Setter},
  {psiIn, psi, ControlType -> Setter},
  {vBwBIn, vBwB, ControlType -> Setter}]
```

to get

[image: manipulate]

I would like to rename the labels (e.g. vAwGIn -> "A". I read how to do it if I initialized the controls but I don't want to do that). I would also like the labels in the Setter buttons and in the result to be in matrix form.

I looked around but haven't found how to do it. :/

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not too hard.

```
Manipulate[
  vBwGFunc[vAwGIn, psiIn, vBwBIn] // MatrixForm, 
  {{vAwGIn, vAwG[[1]], "A"}, Thread[Rule[vAwG, vAwG // MatrixForm]]},
  {{psiIn, psi[[1]], "ψ"}, psi}, 
  {{vBwBIn, vBwB[[1]], "B"}, Thread[Rule[vBwB, vBwB // MatrixForm]]}]
```

[image: matrices]

Comment: Ah, interesting. I didn't think I could set it like that for a list. Thank you very much.

Comment: One additional question, would it be possible to have the selection options be in vector form also? When I tried it, it also came out like you have shown (where selecting a matrix [0 0; 1 1] is set to [1; 0]). Thanks

Comment: @jon. I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you are asking in your most recent comment. Perhaps it would be best if you were to start a new question on _Mathematica_.SE about this addition matter.